# Section Page Adapter getCurrentItem title

Tags: java, android

I have a `tab layout` with 4 `instances` of the same `fragment` but with differents data in the `list`. And i want to get the `current page` so i can change `data` using the title. The problem is that the :`mViewPager.getCurrentItem())` `method` isn't always called.

In `oncreateview` i have :

```
jours2 = new ArrayList<>();
rv = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

adapter = new MyAdapter(jours2);
rv.setAdapter(adapter);
String test= mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(mViewPager.getCurrentItem()).toString();

for (Cours c : jours)
{


    if (c.jour==test)
    {
        jours2.add(c);

    }
}
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

So i can i change my code so it always get the `current` item `title`.

SectionPageAdapter :

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    ArrayList<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> titles = new ArrayList<>();
    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }
    public void AddFragment(Fragment fragment,String title)
    {
        fragments.add(fragment);
        titles.add(title);
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        return fragments.get(position);


    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return fragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return titles.get(position);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please post your mSectionPagerAdapter code

Comment: @RaviTeja I updated my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use this to get the position

```
tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
              tab.getPosition();     
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
```

or you can simply use `tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition()`.